# Sysbench Illegal Instruction

Tags: cpu, benchmarks

I tried to run sysbench on an old server(Intel Xeon 3.2GHz, Ubuntu Server 17.10), and I got "Illegal Instruction (core dumped)" error. I used the following command:

```
sysbench --test-cpu --num-threads=4 --cpu-max-primes=2000 run
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the contents of /proc/cpuinfo I think this might be your old cpu is not able to do the instructions on sysbench. That particular benchmark might not be posible to run on that cpu. As such it would unfortaetly be imposible.